# Test category is not filtering the test and getting run the filtered tests

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, mstest, tfsbuild

I am following the below link to run automated test (All test are MSTest) in a distributed fashion. But in this scenario, the test suite is a very large set. It has more than 4000 test and it takes more time to execute. Hence what I did was added a test category and filtered the tests. 
I have four categories now. Lets call them A,B,C,D

I have 2 issues here.

**My Issue No 1:** 
When I apply the test filter criteria as below attached in TFS ,

[image]

I am not able to run any of the test. Below is the log message

```
2016-05-22T06:15:13.2782759Z Executing the powershell script: C:\Users\Devadmin\Downloads\agent\tasks\RunVisualStudioTestsusingTestAgent\1.0.36\RunDistributedTests.ps1
2016-05-22T06:15:13.7157792Z DistributedTests: Environment WinRm Protocol HTTPS.
2016-05-22T06:15:13.7157792Z DistributedTests: Run Settings File Path : c:\BuildAgent\6\s\UITestSettings.testsettings
2016-05-22T06:15:14.1650306Z DistributedTests: Creating run for selected test assemblies with following parameters
2016-05-22T06:15:14.1650306Z DistributedTests: SourceFilter: **\*UITest*.dll TestCaseFilter: TestCategory=MyTests
2016-05-22T06:15:14.1650306Z DistributedTests: Run title: TestRun Dev Build (Automation)_2314422.17
2016-05-22T06:15:14.1650306Z DistributedTests: is automated: True
2016-05-22T06:15:14.1650306Z DistributedTests: test settings id : 588
2016-05-22T06:15:14.1650306Z DistributedTests: build location: C:\Users\Timothy.Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\UITest
2016-05-22T06:15:14.1650306Z DistributedTests: build id: 1351
2016-05-22T06:15:14.1650306Z DistributedTests: test configuration mapping: 
2016-05-22T06:15:14.3369186Z DistributedTests: Test Run with Id 1674 Queued
2016-05-22T06:15:14.4090887Z DistributedTests: Test run '1674' is in 'InProgress' state.
2016-05-22T06:15:24.4579403Z DistributedTests: Test run '1674' is in 'InProgress' state.
2016-05-22T06:15:34.5147956Z DistributedTests: Test run '1674' is in 'InProgress' state.
2016-05-22T06:15:44.5506966Z DistributedTests: Test run '1674' is in 'InProgress' state.
2016-05-22T06:15:54.5948044Z DistributedTests: Test run '1674' is in 'InProgress' state.
2016-05-22T06:16:04.6407774Z DistributedTests: Test run '1674' is in 'Aborted' state.
2016-05-22T06:16:14.6563930Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
2016-05-22T06:16:15.1940716Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: New test run created.
2016-05-22T06:16:15.1942838Z ##[warning]Test Run queued for Project Collection Build Service 
2016-05-22T06:16:15.1942838Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test discovery started.
2016-05-22T06:16:15.1942838Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test Run Discovery Aborted . Test run id : 1674
2016-05-22T06:16:15.1942838Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.
2016-05-22T06:16:15.1942838Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Error : No tests were discovered from the specified test sources
2016-05-22T06:16:15.1942838Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 1674
2016-05-22T06:16:15.2099252Z ##[error]The test run was aborted, failing the task.
```

Comment: Which link did you follow? If you don't apply the test filter criteria, are you able to have this step pass?

Comment: Are your test assemblies copied to the build location correctly? And can you share the testesettings file?

Answer (score 0):

The error log indicates "No tests were discovered from the specified test sources", you need to check the settings in your step "[Visual Studio Test using Test Agent Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/RunDistributedTests/README.md)", and make sure this step is preceded with “Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment” task.